# How to set tab title when opening a new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am opening a new tab like this

```
$('#HelpMenu li a').on('click', function (e) {
    let linkToAppendTo = "http://help.mysite.com/" + e.target.innerText;
    let openTab = window.open(linkToAppendTo, "_blank");
    openTab.focus();
});
```

and don't know how to change the opening tabs title.

As for the provided link that is only changing a current tab title, not a new one that has been opened as I am showing

Comment: Is the site you're linking to on the same domain? You may be running into cross-domain issues which will prevent you from modifying the opened window.

Comment: if help.mysite.com/<innerText> is your own website, it should have a <title> tag within that you can set the tab title to. or are you really trying to dynamically generate the title?

Comment: @DanielBeck, I beleive you are right. Right now I am running off localhost and not running the app on the server yet. You might want to use that as your answer incase anyone else runs across the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the title on the onload event for the new tab.

```
openTab.onload = function() { this.document.title = "Title"; }
```

Comment: Didn't change the newly opened tab

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let openTab = window.open(linkToAppendTo, "_blank");
openTab.document.title = "Some title";
```